# SQL Update Not Performing How I'd Like Inside While Loop Using Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a foreign key Id, as well as a "Rank" field. The rank value is mostly arbitrary, and is decided based on the amount of other related objects with the matching foreign key Id. So for instance, if I have 3 rows with the same foreign key Id, they would each have a ranking of 0, 1, and 2, respectively, and if I created a new row that has the same foreign key Id, this new row would have a Rank value of 3.

My issue comes when I need to delete a row and then update the ranking. For instance, if I delete the row that has a rank of 1, I would like to update the higher value rankings to "fill in the gap". For example, if I have 4 rows that go, in order of ranking, 0, 1, 2, 3 and I delete the Rank 2 row, I would like the updated order of ranking to be 0, 1, 2.

I have tried using a cursor to traverse only the rows that have the associated foreign key Id, and have been able to see that I am successfully traversing, but have been unable to successfully see that the values have been updated correctly in my table. I think using a counter object that starts at 0 and increments by 1 for each row and sets this value to the current row's Rank value should serve my purpose, I just haven't been able to successfully get the program to run as intended.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18.

I have provided the code I am currently using.

```
declare @Counter int = 0;
declare @Id varchar(50);
set @Id = '35d9593f-e41f-4361-9156-c03042d7a925';

declare CURS cursor FOR
    select *
    from #Table
    Where Id = @Id
    Order By Rank;

Open CURS;
FETCH NEXT FROM CURS;

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    UPDATE #Table
    SET Rank = @Counter;

    Set @Counter += 1

    fetch next from CURS
End
Close CURS
GO
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is "working" - the code does exactly what you wrote. In your loop, you update **every row in the table** with the current value of your loop counter. If you want to use cursors, you need to educate yourself about how to use them. You can make it (the cursor) updateable. OTOH cursors are rarely used in tsql and a topic that should wait until you have mastered basic sql.

Comment: Yeah I have likely gotten a little in over my head with the solutions I've been looking into. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: There's absolutely no need for a cursor or loop here, and changing this to avoid them will likely make it at least two orders of magnitude faster, and require much less code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead, use an updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by rank) as seqnum
      from #test t
     )
update toupdate
    set rank = seqnum - 1;
```

No looping.  No cursors.  No variables.  And it should be much faster.

Comment: How would this look if I wanted to update the rank of just the values based on a certain foreign key Id? For example, in my table I have 3 rows associated with a foreign key Id, and am using the Rank field to order them (like 1, 2, 3 for each respective object). My attempted solution comes from when I need to delete a row and then update the ranking (like going from 1, 2, 3 -> 1, 3 -> then updating the ranking to 1, 2)

Comment: @tony You should [edit] and update your question with what you are trying to do. In all likelihood, you change this answer and add a `where` filter or a `partition by`

Comment: @Charlieface thanks, just did. First time ever posting here so I could definitely still use improvement in best explaining my problem.

Comment: @Tony . . . If you only want one id, then add a `where` in the CTE:  `where id = @id`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify Gordon's query to partition the numbering by `id`:

```sql
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by rank) as seqnum
      from #test t
     )
update toupdate
    set rank = seqnum - 1;
```

To get the correct ranking just for a single foreign key, you can make a slight modification:

```sql
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             row_number() over (order by rank) as seqnum
      from #test t
      where Id = @id
     )
update toupdate
    set rank = seqnum - 1;
```

After you delete or insert a row, just run this query again.

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface